# Help with simplifying with $a+bi$ format?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can someone please explain to me why $\frac{3}{2+4i}$ simplified into $a+bi$ format is $\frac{3}{10}-\frac{3i}{5}$? I can't find any explanations of what $a+bi$ format is.

Thank you, and this is from precalculus.

Comment: Please use more parentheses:  is$ 3/5i$ supposed to be $(3/5)i$ or $3/(5i)$ which are additive inverses?

Comment: (3/5)i is what it is supposed to  be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:  Multiplying both the numerator and denominator by the conjugate of the denominator, which is $2-4i$.

\begin{align}
\frac3{2+4i}&=\frac{3\cdot(2-4i)}{(2+4i)(2-4i)}\\
\\&=\frac{3(2-4i)}{4-16(i)(i)}\\
\\&=\frac{3(2-4i)}{4-16(-1)}, \text{ since $i^2=-1$}\\
\\&=\frac{3(2-4i)}{20}\\
\\&=\frac6{20}-\frac{12i}{20}\\
\\&=\frac{3}{10}-\frac{3i}{5}\\
\end{align}
Thus $a=\frac3{10}$ and $b=\frac35.$

Or you can use this [division formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Multiplication_and_division).

Comment: Can you please explain what i means? How did you go from step 2 to step 3?

Comment: I've edited it.

Comment: so basically i is sqrt(-1) Thats the main key for solving this problem I need to know?

Comment: Yes, $i=\sqrt{-1}$ so $i\times i=\sqrt{-1}\times\sqrt{-1}=-1$...

Comment: and a is the side without i, and b with i?

Comment: You got it! $a$ is the real part, and $b$ is the imaginary part, or just simply, the part with the $i$ component

Comment: Wow thanks! It makes sense to me now! Thank you so much.

Comment: You are very welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You have $\frac 3{(2+4i)}=\frac {3(2-4i)}{20}=\frac {2-4i}6=\frac 3{10}-\frac {3i}5$.   $\ \ \ a+bi$ format is a representation of complex numbers where $a$ and $b$ are both real.

Comment: What is i? How did you go from 2+4i to 18?

Comment: I multiplied by the conjugate, $2-4i$ top and bottom, getting $2^2+4^2=20$.  Fixed.